# BizTalk SOAP receive location poor performance

Tags: performance, soap, biztalk, asmx

I've encountered poor performance in my BizTalk application that uses SOAP/ASMX Receive location web service hosted in IIS on the same sever. This service only invoke one function on Oracle DB (connected via Oracle Driver)

I've done load tests via Soap UI and I stressed DB a little from PL/SQL Profiler in SQL Navigator and it turned out that avg request time = 700ms, avg DB query time = 15ms, avg Orchestration done time = 30ms (via BT Admin Console), so there is an tremendous amount of time wasting by IIS, asmx or SOAP?

I've read this: [Configuration Parameters that Affect Adapter Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configuration-parameters-that-affect-adapter-performance) and tweaked minFreeThreads , minFreeLocalRequestFreeThreads but nothing really happened.

But as I understand well - there is send port described there and I have problem Receive Location, right?

Also read that article: [BizTalk: Performance problems using the SOAP adapter](https://zeetalks.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/biztalk-performance-problems-using-the-soap-adapter/)

There is no such key like:

Registry Key:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTSSvc$BizTalkServerApplication\CLR Hosting
```

How to achieve Option 2?

Option 2:

Look into process isolation – this would using a different instance of the .NET threadpool executed in a separate address space from the BizTalk NT service.

Guide me please

Comment: Do you have an actual .asmx page?  BizTalk does not use .asmx pages.  The Receive Location is an ISAPI App.  Also, what do you mean 'connected by Oracle Driver?"  Are you using the Oracle DB Adapter?

Comment: @Johns-305 Yes, there is no site and its ISAPI,  and no, application use Oracle DB Client not Oracle adapter

Comment: Sorry, you're not using the Oracle Adapter with BizTalk?

Comment: That article is rather old (2009). Later version of BizTalk have those configuration settings in Settings for the Host in the Admin Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your receive host properties and change message polling interval to 50ms from default 500ms, that will provide an improved performance. If you're using orchestration on a separate host to process service request and response, do the same on orchestration host but reduce orchestration polling interval. Doing this increase performance for low latency scenario, however it adds overhead on SQL message box. Depending on your volume and need tune this.

Also try upgrading to WCF services

Comment: If you are going to reduce the polling on the host, I'd recommend creating new LowLatency hosts & host instances, and only putting those that require it on there.  This will reduce the impact on the SQL message box.

Comment: Reduce polling on ServerIsolatedHost ? I did that and indeed time went down to 450ms, but Im afraid that it will have bad influence on rest of Receive Locations

Comment: Ive also realized that in order to apply changes I needed to recycle AppPool in IIS